# Volley doesnt work, unable to find the error

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to change my code from ServiceHandler, Parsing and Asynctask to Volley. I compiled the latest version this evening. The AsyncTask is working fine. 
For some reason I cant find the error in the volley part. How I can check if the params get posted? I read something about VolleyErrorHelper here http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/ but I cant implement it.

I get always the error:

```
05-02 20:11:55.997: D/Volley(5543): [1] 2.onErrorResponse: TAG
```

My code (from androidhive):

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Button", "Login");
                name = inputName.getText().toString();
                password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                //new loginasynctask().execute();
                // Tag used to cancel the request
                String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

                String url = "URLYOUDONT/index.php";

                        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                                url, null,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                        Log.d("TAG", response.toString());

                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                                    }
                                }) {

                            @Override
                            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                params.put("tag", "login");
                                params.put("name", name);
                                params.put("password", password);
                                return params;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                                return params;
                            }

                        };

                // Adding request to request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Change your log, maybe there is no error message, but still there is an error `VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error);` (also you can debug and breakpoint at this point at see what `error` contains

Comment: I changed to code, but still nor error message,...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while using volley. No matter what i did, error logs wouldn't show in the logcat.

I handled that by debugging with android studio. My request was timeouting.

[image]